# Forcing HTTPS/SSL for All Site Pages

Tags: python, ssl, flask, https, pythonanywhere

I am new to web design. I have a Python Flask web app through pythonanywhere.com. I set up an SSL certificate through pythonanywhere, and   it works fine for the index page. All subdomains (*x*.mysite.com) of the index page redirect to HTTPS. But if someone goes to a subpage of the site (mysite.com/*x*) without explicitly specifying https, they get a NOT SECURE warning.

I have tried the Force HTTPS option that pythonanywhere provides, as well as using Flask-SSLify, but the problem persists. Both of these options seem to assume that all URL paths will be redirected to HTTPS, but that is not happening. Is there something additional I need to do?

Comment: Check [Talisman](https://pypi.org/project/flask-talisman/) out. Forcing HTTPS is just one of many security best-practices that it includes.

Comment: what is the exact not secure warning that you see- can you give more details on that?

Comment: I am running into the same problems with Talisman. The not secure warning is the same I get for any site without HTTPS. On Safari it is a blank page, with 'Not Secure' indicated in the search bar.

Comment: This sounds like the kind of problem that people would be better able to debug if they could see it in their browser.  Would it be possible for you to share some real URLs?

Comment: For example, if straight-think.com/pi/ is used, there is a Not Secure warning. If straight-think.com is used, there are no problems (and most browsers seem to remember the URL, so that straight-think.com/pi/ then works until the browser history is deleted).

Answer (score 0):

It appears that whatever you're using to redirect straight-think.com to www.straight-think.com does not do the redirect for any path other than /. Using "Force HTTPS", talisman or Flask-SSLify will not have any effect, because the request does not get far enough to reach the web app on PythonAnywhere where those things would be applied.

The apparent caching of success that you're seeing is just the result of the url having www. prepended to it (most browsers hide that at the moment) so it appears as if straight-think.com/pi/ starts working, but it's actully because the browser has switched ot www.straight-think.com invisibly.

I would suggest disabling the redirect that you currently have an instead use [NakedSSL](https://www.nakedssl.com/) to do your redirection.